# When will dealloc be called on UIViewController when it's getting popped?

Tags: ios, uikit

Say if I have a navigation stack like this: **UINavigationController->ViewController1->ViewController2**. When ViewController2 gets popped, does the system guarantee the executing order of below methods?

1. *dealloc* of ViewController2
2. *viewWillAppear* of ViewController1

I've tested for a while and only see *dealloc* is called first, but I don't know if this can be guaranteed, i.e., is it also possible ViewController1's *viewWillAppear* gets called before ViewController2's *dealloc*?

Comment: Yes, it will be deallocated unless it creates a circular reference cycle (memory leak).

Comment: @Desdenova Sorry I didn't make myself clear. I was asking if dealloc of ViewController2 is guaranteed to be called before viewWillAppear of ViewController2

Answer (score 1):

There is no such guarantee of order, and it's even likely `viewWillAppear` of your ViewController1 is called before `ViewController2.dealloc` is called.

The reason is that depending on autorelease pools and internal references, it's likely the system still has a reference to the view controller that is just disappearing/has just disappeared when it calls the `viewWillAppear` of the view controller that's *about* to get shown.

If you require cleanup to be run when ViewController2 is popped, implement `viewWillDisappear`/`viewDidDisappear`. Again, there is no guarantee that `vc2.viewWillDisappear` will be called before `vc1.viewWillAppear`, but you can rely on `vc2.viewWillDisappear` getting called before `vc1.viewDidAppear` (note `Did`, not `Will` in the last one).